# django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution on highload

Tags: django, docker, high-load

I have the django project which works with PostGresql db, both in docker containers.
It works Ok, but on highload sometimes gives the
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution`
error.
Is there a way to tune the django db connector for more retries or more timeout to solve these case?

docker-compose.yml (with some changes) :

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: ./django
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command:
      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      django_volume:/home/django/django/files/
    ports:
      8000:8000
    env_file:
      env.django
    depends_on:
      db

  db:
    build: 
      context: ./db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      env.db

volumes:
  django_volume:
  db_volume:
```

django container's entrypoint.sh contains the cycle:

```
while ! nc -x $DB_HOST $DB_PORT ; do
  sleep 0.1
done

exec "$@"
```

To be sure that db completely started before django start.

Comment: Do you have depends_on in your django container and healthcheck in postgresql container?

Comment: Yes. As I said, all works Ok on low or medium workload. It happens only when I send long row of requests (250-300) without any delay between them.

Comment: Would you mind to show your compose file?

Comment: Yes. I added them to the question text.